# Use multiprocessing for a for loop, Python

Tags: python, for-loop, multiprocessing

I have a for loop, which uses some binary conditions and finally writes a file accordingly. The problem I have is, the conditions are true for many files (sometimes around 1000 files need to be written). So writing them takes a long time (around 10 mins). I know I can somehow use Python's `multiprocessing` and utilise some of the cores.

This is the code that works, but only uses one core.

```
for i,n in enumerate(halo_param.strip()):
    mask = var1['halo_id'] == n
    newtbdata = tbdata1[mask]
    hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU(newtbdata)
    hdu.writeto(('/home/Documments/file_{0}.fits').format(i))
```

I came across that it can be done using `Pool` from `multiprocessing`.

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)`

I would like to know how to do it and utilise atleast 4 of my cores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restructure the for loop body as a function, and use [`Pool.map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) with the function.

```
def work(arg):
    i, n = arg
    mask = var1['halo_id'] == n
    newtbdata = tbdata1[mask]
    hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU(newtbdata)
    hdu.writeto(('/home/Documments/file_{0}.fits').format(i))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(work, enumerate(halo_param.strip()))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: so by saying `i,n = arg` when we call `pool.map` the function takes the arg to be `enumerate(halo_param.strip())`. But how does it loop? I don't see any loops here, but it seems to work!

Comment: @ThePredator, `multiprocessing.Pool.map` works like a builtin function [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map). `map` apply the given function for each item of the sequence (or any iterable, the second argument). Follow the link if you want to know more about the `map` function.